# git management - user rights

Tags: git, file-permissions, access-control

I have to set up git for a development team. The team members must have different rights.

Some roles should have read rights only, some should be able to push but not to create new branches or tags. Only a selected group of people should be allowed to do merges. This are just some examples.

After all: Is there a way to set up fine grained access control for git? What would be a good software stack to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if folks clone (read) a repository, they can branch / tag / merge etc all day long because its their clone now and you will never have any control over what they are doing with their files. the only thing you can control is who pushes stuff into your central repository (that you want to use as a dropin-replacement for subversion as it seems).

if you trust only person x or person y to be able to cleanly maintain the one central repository, then you should allow only these persons write access to the fold which contains the repository.

the 2 most popular approaches to (self)host writable git-repositories are:

- [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)
- [gitosis](http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git) (mostly obsolete nowadays, use gitolite)

to just allow read-access you can use git itself. also a good read: http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/2/building-your-own-git-server